# Symfony 5.4 missing Dev bundles in Production

Tags: php, symfony

I want to deploy my symfony application in production using the command composer install require --no-dev however I get the following error :

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError^ {#97
  #message: """
    Attempted to load class "NelmioAliceBundle" from namespace "Nelmio\Alice\Bridge\Symfony".\n
    Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
    """
  #code: 0
  #file: "/Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php"
  #line: 132
  trace: {
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:132 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:386 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:786 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:128 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:168 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:74 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:54 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/vendor/autoload_runtime.php:35 { …}
    /Users/tom/Documents/test-rh-rh/www/bin/console:11 {
```

I tried to specify the environment by adding SYMFONY_ENV=prod as specified in the doc but without success.

how do I deploy production bundles only?

Comment: Don't use dev packages in prod services.

Comment: Looks like everything is working properly, as you haven't deployed a dev dependency. But how do you use it? Did you check in your bundles.php whether that bundle might be used in any other environment?

Comment: hello @NicoHaase I have this line in my bundles.php :     Nelmio\Alice\Bridge\Symfony\NelmioAliceBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],

Comment: @NicoHaase I have a fixture directory in my project which contains all aliceBundle fixtures

Comment: So, your application does not directly load that bundle, that's a good one. But for which reason do you use `SYMFONY_ENV=prod`? How is the application environment itself configured? That should be `APP_ENV`

Comment: @NicoHaase I used the specifications from the symfony website because I don't have symfony flex and indeed https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#c-install-update-your-vendors when I use APP_ENV it works perfectly. thank you very